# Facebook login problems

Tags: facebook, login

I have been facing a weird problem regarding login to Facebook account:

I have two PCs; PC1 at home and PC2 at my office. I created my Facebook account from PC1. Now, I can log in to my Facebook account from PC1 but I'm not able to do it from PC2. Whenever I try to log in from PC2 I keep getting this message:

```
Incorrect Email
The email you entered does not belong to any account. You may try clearing ....
```

Now the most unusual part comes.

I am able to create a new Facebook account from PC2 using the same email that I had used while creating my account from PC1. Actually, Facebook should say that this account is already registered.

Can someone throw some light here as to what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you verify your email address.

Comment: Yes the email address is verified and I am able to log in to Face Book account from PC1 already. I have also tried to access my account on FaceBook from a Cyber Cafe and from there also I get the same error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an error with your account. You may have to contact Facebook through their forms. Such as the [Report a Login Issue](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=357439354283890) form.